# VBA, найти и скопировать

Tags: excel, vba

Необходима из столбца (например B) найти все ячейки с определенным текстом (например `<name>` или `<desc>`) и скопировать их в другой столбец (например С) в том же ряду.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ```C1=IF( INSTR( B1, "<name>" ) > 0 , B1, "" )```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sheetName, myString As String
Dim x As Integer

sheetName =    'сюда присвоите название листа (в двойных кавычках например "Лист1") вашей книги, где требуется выполнить макрос.
х =            ' здесь, присвоите порядковый номер столбца от 0 до N слева направо, где нулевой столбец - это столбец А, 1-й - столбец B и так далее.
myString =     'здесь присвоите часть значения, которое нужно найти в ячейках (в двойных кавычках разумеется!!!

With Sheets(sheetName).Range("A1")
  Do While .Offset(i,x) <> ""     
    If InStr(1, .Offset(i,x), myString) > 0 Then
       .Offset(i,x+1).Value = .Offset(i,x).Value
    End If

   i=i+1   ' не забудьте эту строку с инкрементом!!! Иначе всё зависнет!
  Loop
End With
```

По итогу выполнения кода, вы получите таблицу, в которой из всех ячеек столбца номер "X" будут копированы значения ячеек в соседний (справа) столбец, если они будут содержать в своём значении строку "myString"
ВНИМАНИЕ! Код обработает столбец с номером указанным в X до первой пустой ячейки в этом столбце. То есть, он для неразрывного диапазона любого размера подходит, т.к конец диапазона определяется первой встреченной пустой ячейкой в столбце. Если вам нужно перебрать известный диапазон (по размеру, например 1000 строк в столбце), независимо от того будут ли встреченные пустые ячейки, то замените строку:

```
Do While .Offset(i,x) <> ""
' на строку:
Do While i <> 1000   'вместо 1000 количество строк которые нужно обработать в таблице
```